# can i integrate BlackBerry inApp payment into my android application?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

im trying to integrate inapp purchases (from blackberry market) into my android application.
when i import this library "**paymentapi.jar**" into my project and run it i receive these warnings/errors:

```
[2012-10-12 15:28:43 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.rimlib.blackberry.api.paymentsdk.a) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-10-12 15:28:43 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.rimlib.blackberry.api.paymentsdk.digitalGoods.a) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-10-12 15:28:43 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.rimlib.blackberry.api.paymentsdk.paymentInstruments.a) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-10-12 15:28:43 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.rimlib.blackberry.api.paymentsdk.paymentInstruments.b) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-10-12 15:28:43 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.rimlib.blackberry.api.paymentsdk.purchaseHistory.a) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-10-12 15:28:43 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.rimlib.a.a.a.b) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-10-12 15:28:43 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.rimlib.a.a.a.c) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-10-12 15:28:43 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.rimlib.a.a.a.d) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-10-12 15:28:43 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.rimlib.a.a.a.e) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-10-12 15:28:43 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.rimlib.a.a.a.f) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-10-12 15:28:43 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.rimlib.a.a.a.i) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-10-12 15:28:43 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.rimlib.a.a.a.k) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-10-12 15:28:43 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Dx 
EXCEPTION FROM SIMULATION:
[2012-10-12 15:28:43 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Dx local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.Object using a local variable of type boolean. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.

[2012-10-12 15:28:43 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Dx ...at bytecode offset 00000013
locals[0000]: I
locals[0001]: Lnet/rim/device/api/system/CodeSigningKey;
stack[top0]: I
...while working on block 0012
...while working on method b:(I)Z
...while processing b (I)Z
...while processing net/rimlib/a/a/b/b.class

[2012-10-12 15:28:55 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-10-12 15:28:55 - com.jcentricity.forecastica.lite.activity.LoginActivity_BlackBerry] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

i've tried lots of "**clean project**", "java build path", close eclipse etc...

thanks!

Comment: Are you intending to release your Android app for BlackBerry-10 and BlackBerry Playbook, via the Android-player mechanism?  If not, it's hard to understand why you would want to do this.

Comment: The payment API you are using is for BlackBerry Java-ME, which won't work.  Find out what RIM has in mind for in-app payments for the Android-player apps running on BlackBerry-10.

Comment: Alabala, did you ever get a resolution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do this.

The BlackBerry Java-ME in-app billing system uses classes specific to the BlackBerry Java-ME platform. Due to this, you won't even be able to compile your app, let alone run it. As the Android platform does not support the BlackBerry SDK, you will not be able to use the BlackBerry library to have in app purchases.

Instead, you can use Android's own [in app purchase system](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/index.html) to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: Use RIM's in app purchase system.

Comment: http://blogs.blackberry.com/2011/03/in-app-payments/
http://devblog.blackberry.com/2011/01/blackberry-payment-service/

Comment: That's because you're using BlackBerry libraries in an Android project. For Android, use the Google in app system. For BlackBerry, use the RIM one. Not vice versa.

Comment: yes that is my question. if i want to use blackberry app world do i need to create a blackberry project and port the application(im using eclipse)?

Comment: Okay. Let me make this simple. **You cannot use RIM in app purchases in Android apps.** If you want in app items in an Android app, use the Google API for it. Don't touch BlackBerry with the Android project at all. They are completely unrelated.

Comment: so do i need to create a blackberry project and write the application from beginning? that was the question... there is no other way to reuse my android code for blackberry app world?

Comment: You may be able to reuse certain Java logic code, but all API and in app purchase code would have to be rewritten.

Comment: The question is actually about the Android player used on BlackBerry-10 and BlackBerry Playbook.  The initial confusion is that the Java-ME API will not work on an Android app.  However, RIM may still have an in-app payment API for the Android-player apps.

Comment: @RaghavSood i have integrated google in app billing v2, but its not working can you please help me with that.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921929/blackberry-in-app-purchase-not-working-after-integrating-google-iap-v2

Answer (score -1):

But it says Android supports inApp purchase so how?

http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/apisupport_inapp_payments_support.html

Comment: It's not clear if you are trying to answer the question, or comment on it.